# Prevent Wine application from checking for DirectX

Tags: wine, directx

I am trying to install an application in Wine. The program will only work on Windows 95, so I set this option in `winecfg`. But when I run the installer, it checks if DirectX 3.0 is installed, and however it does that checking causes Wine to crash. Can I prevent the application from doing this check?